# json_decode returns JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX in OpenCart

Tags: javascript, json, opencart

I am working on the admin interface of an OpenCart shipping extention.

I have a form that has a hidden field, this field is populated by `JSON.stringify(rules)` on the front end

The variable `rules` is a multi-tiered object.

In the controller I can read the `$this->request->post['rules']` variable and the looks to be valid JSON, but `json_last_error()` gives me `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`

I check that my JSON is UTF-8 with `mb_detect_encoding()` (returns `ASCII`)
and I have 
removed invalid charicters with the following code

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; ++$i) { 
    $rules = str_replace(chr($i), "", $rules); 
}
$rules = str_replace(chr(127), "", $rules);

if (0 === strpos(bin2hex($rules), 'efbbbf')) {
    $rules = substr($rules, 3);
 }
```

an example of my generated JSON"

```
{"SMEVT":{"id":"SMEVT","name":"Free","high":99999,"low":575,"amount":0,"type":1},"VZWSR":{"id":"VZWSR","name":"25%","high":575,"low":0,"amount":25,"type":1}}
```

I cant figure out what `json_decode` will not work. Thanks for any help.

UPDATE:

I used `strlen($rules)` and discovered the string was much longer that expected, seems OpenCart(or somthingelse) is adding `&quot;` in place of the `"` in the JSON string.

Anyone know of an easy way to clean this up?

Comment: do a `var_dump($this->request->post['rules'])`. You should not be mangling the json string with `str_replace` and the like. those functions aren't unicode safe.

Comment: you've tagged this with javascript and json, but it looks like you're using PHP. If you're trying to use JS to parse JSON, you need to use `JSON.parse(str)`.

Comment: JSON lint returns "Valid JSON"... Maybe [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in generated file?

Comment: your example is valid `JSON` and `json_decode()` works on it. please provide more code or an example on which `json_decode()` fails.

Comment: Marc B, output of `var_dump($this->request->post['rules'])` is
`string(337) "{"IRIYL":{"id":"IRIYL","name":"Free","high":99999,"low":575,"amount":0,"type":1},"YWHDM":{"id":"YWHDM","name":"25%","high":575,"low":0,"amount":25,"type":1}}"`

I did not add the `str_replace` util after I realised the issue, I have removed no , as it dod not resolve the issue.

Comment: zzzzBov, I tagged javascript as the JSON is created with js `JSON.stringify(rules)`, but then are read in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems OpenCart (or somthing else) was changing the `"` (quotes) to `&quot;`, therby breaking the JSON.

I added the following line befor I decode the JSON, this fixed the issue.

`$rules = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $rules);`

Comment: Great, it works well